# What is this board game with black & white pieces and criss-crossing lines called? or how is it played?

Tags: identify-this-game

I found this image on Pinterest with description "Ancient board game".

[image: Ancient board game]

There are more than 15 black and white pieces, some of them are placed on the intersection of 3 vertical lines and other criss-crossing lines.

What is it called and how to play?

Comment: funny enough this image came from BGG where the name was right there

Answer (score 5):

This is a game called "**[Fighting Serpents](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13656/fighting-serpents)**" or "**[Kolowis Awithlaknannai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolowis_Awithlaknannai)**",
and in particular this is a version of that game produced by a Greek company by the name of [Elite Crafters](https://www.elitecrafters.com/en/ancient-fighting-serpents-decorative-board-game-set-handmade-ceramic-table-art-decor-ornament-replica-51cm-20).

The game originally comes from the Zuni people of New Mexico, but its most likely a modified version of Alquerque, which was introduced by the Spanish while they were exploring the Americas.

Comment: Do we know if it is a "solved" game (that is, if we know if it is a fair game with perfect play or if one of the players has the advantage)?

Comment: While, much like Alquerque, the game hasn't been solved, they are both closely related to Checkers (English draughts), which has been solved, showing that with perfect play either player can force a draw; This game would most likely follow the same pattern.